# Is there actually a "pad(3NCURSES)" manual page?

Tags: ncurses

In the man page for `ncurses(3X)`, we read:

> Special windows called pads may also be manipulated. These are windows which are not
> constrained to the size of the screen and whose contents need not be completely displayed.
> See `pad(3NCURSES)` for more information.

I have been unable to locate a manpage for `pad` though. Does it exist or is this just an uncorrected leftover text in the manual?

There is a manpage for `curs_pad(3X)`, which is also the only one brought up by `apropos pad`:

> `newpad`, `subpad`, `prefresh`, `pnoutrefresh`, `pechochar`,
> `pecho_wchar` - create and display curses pads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian renames the ncurses manual page for stylistic reasons.  The ncurses sources have scripts and data-files used for this purpose:

- [man_db.renames](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/man/man_db.renames), e.g.,

  curs_pad.3x         pad.3ncurses
- the configure script, documented in [INSTALL](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/91e57fba4ceb88ece7ca7208dd28e1abddd41408/INSTALL#L1064):

> --with-manpage-renames=XXX
>
> Tell the configure script that you wish to rename the manpages while
> installing.  Currently the only distribution which does this is Debian.
> The option value specifies the name of a file that lists the renamed
> files, e.g., $srcdir/man/man_db.renames

It's been there a while (at least since [June 1996](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t960601), though a comment in the Debian bug-report says it was October 1995 — when the changelog omitted details like this):

```
960601  - snapshot
        + auto-configure man-page compression-format and renames for Debian.
```

The html-manpages used in the ncurses-doc package in Debian are the generated source-files from upstream, which use the original filenames.  There's a Debian bug report ([#618429](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=618429)) dealing with that, which would require Debian to regenerate the html files to match the non-html naming convention to resolve it.

Likewise, those files are the starting point for the upstream website's [manual pages](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/index.html).

Other distributions, such as Fedora, do not use this renaming.  For instance, in [Fedora 33](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/33/x86_64/n/ncurses-devel-6.2-3.20200222.fc33.x86_64.html) the pathnames look like this:

```
/usr/share/man/man3/curs_pad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/field_pad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/is_keypad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/is_pad.3x.gz  
/usr/share/man/man3/keypad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/menu_pad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/newpad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/newpad_sp.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/set_field_pad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/set_menu_pad.3x.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/subpad.3x.gz
```

while Debian (and derived stuff such as Ubuntu) have

```
/usr/share/doc/ncurses-doc/html/man/curs_pad.3x.html
/usr/share/man/man3/pad.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/field_pad.3form.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/is_keypad.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/is_pad.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/keypad.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/menu_pad.3menu.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/newpad.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/newpad_sp.3ncurses.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/set_field_pad.3form.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/set_menu_pad.3menu.gz  
/usr/share/man/man3/subpad.3ncurses.gz
```

You would make the man program distinguish ncurses' "pad" from some other by putting the section first:

```
man 3ncurses pad
```

or

```
man 3NCURSES pad
```

(since it seems to ignore case on the section name).

Debian's package-changelog for ncurses-doc does not mention when the renaming-feature was first added, since it starts about a year later:

```
ncurses (1.9.9g-1) unstable; urgency=low
  
  * New maintainer
  * New upstream version (fixes #9219)
  * Built with libc6
  * Libraries compiled with -D_REENTRANT
  * Quick fix for termcap emulation (fixes #1045)
  * Linked reset manpage to tset manpage (fixes #3192, #8187, #9921)
  * Library package no longer "Essential" (fixes #3801)
  
 -- Galen Hazelwood <galen@micron.net>  Thu, 12 Jun 1997 12:18:34 -0600
```

It is mentioned about another year later:

```
ncurses (1.9.9g-8.7) frozen unstable; urgency=low
  
  * For reasons that I don't understand, using ncurses3.4 >= 1.9.9g-8.1 with
    ncurses3.4-dev 1.9.9g-8.6 causes lxdialog (kernel's make menuconfig)
    to segfault. Changed the dependency to >= Source-Version. (Fixes
    release-critical #24392).
  * More manpages fixes (Fixes #24400): 
    * [aclocal.m4] Rewrote the manpages fixing code somewhat so that
      references like "\fBcurses\fR(3X), " get handled correctly
    * [man/curs_termcap.3x] Minor changes, so that references get translated
      properly.
    * [man/man_db.renames] Added terminfo.\*n and curs_terminfo.\*n .   
 
 -- J.H.M. Dassen (Ray) <jdassen@wi.LeidenUniv.nl>  Sat, 11 Jul 1998 16:28:21 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am on Fedora 33, so this renaming seems to apply not only to Debian. now.

Comment: I don't see that in the package for Fedora 33 -- see update

Comment: That's so long ago I was still at uni. Anyway, so on Fedora, `man curs_pad` and `man 'curs_pad(3X)'` work whereas `man 'pad(3ncurses)'` does not (I can confirm). However on Debian `man 'pad(3ncurses)'` would, indeedm work. And thus the man page for `ncurses` I find on Fedora is actually meant for Debian?